# The cube of at least one irrational number is rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, rationality-testing

> The cube of at least one irrational number is rational

I am supposed to prove the statement above.  Here is what I have so far:

> Suppose that the cube of at least one irrational number $n$, is rational. 
>       By definition of rational, there exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $r = a/b$ 
>       and $b$ is not equal to $0$.  Consequently
>                                               $$\begin{align}n = \sqrt[\Large 3]{\frac ab}\\
>                                             n^3 = \frac ab\end{align}$$

I do not know where to go with the proof from here.  Is that all I need for the equations and am I doing this right?  Or am I going about it completely wrong?

Comment: If all you have to do is show that there exists on irrational number who's cube is rational, just pick an example. Try the cube root of 2. Clearly the cube is rational - it's an integer.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a proof by contradiction of this fact without a constructive proof like showing $2^{1/3}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Henry: Right, but that's exactly a constructive proof like $2^{1/3}$. I'm thinking more along the lines of group theory. For example suppose that instead we were dealing with some subset of the irrationals. How could one show that there exists at least one rational when you cube them all. Or, what conditions on that set would you need for such a statement to be true.

Comment: "Or am I going about it completely wrong?" Yes, you are. You need to prove something, your first line cannot be "Assume the something I need to prove", which is what you do here. It is not the only problem with the argument.

Comment: @AlexR. I imagine such a proof would be to assume that the equation $x^3 = q$ for all rational q has a rational root, since that's effectively what the statement is the opposite of